# CSS not working when am trying to use update panel in my webpage?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, css-float

i have webpages with master page which contain my css...When i add update panel in content palce holder, css on master page are working fine but same css not working in content page holder.

```
<%@ Page Title="District Master" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/webpages/MasterPage_new.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmDistrict.aspx.cs" Inherits="webpages_frmDistrict" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="main_div">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppnl" runat="server" Mode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%; float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 100px; width: 100%; float: left;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px"
                                Width="6%" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnSearchOK_OnClick" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px"
                                Width="11%" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnRefresh_OnClick" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11px"
                                Width="9%" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnClose_OnClick" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: share your css or a piece of it which is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because ASP.NET changes the `id` of all elements in the **Content Panel** and prepends the name of the master like `id="content"` would become `id="body#content"`. To verify check the View Source in your browser.

Solution is to update your CSS according to the generated `ID`s.

Comment: But Ids are generated for server side controls only, if css is implemented on client side elements then it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML code? This happens whenever Masterpages are used. The IDs are always updated

Comment: @Muhammad Ahmad Zafar,@yogi Yess...Ids are generated for server side controls but when am removing update panel css working fine on all webpages...! what can i do with update panel????

Comment: Leave the ASP.NET code and controls as they are and update your CSS and JS (if required). ID selectors in CSS should be renamed with the prepended characters. Again check the View Source from your browse to verify the names.

Comment: @ Muhammad Ahmad Zafar Yess Id's are updated in html i saw in source code but here css classes are  not assigned with ID's only it assigned with control tag (like button table tr td ul li textbox div span etc etc)

Comment: I share css in master page but content place holder not accepted it...then am trying to share it using javascript but it failed to accept again....

Comment: I meant share the code with me so that I can have a look at the problem

Comment: Thanks @ Muhammad Ahmad Zafar i made changes in css..... html control tag from button to input[Type=Submit] & it works fine.